# How to generate entity id for GAE datastore in php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-php-client

i am trying to insert new entity using PHP client library into datastore, i am using datastore_connect.php file from this example, https://github.com/amygdala/appengine_php_datastore_example

I want to insert entity with auto id, not the name. I see that there is function setId(), but i dont know how to generate proper id. Whats the best practice in doing so?

Thanks

```
function createKeyForTestItem () {
    $path = new Google_Service_Datastore_KeyPathElement();
    $path->setKind("testkind");
    $path->setName("testkeyname");
    //$path->setId(??)
    $key = new Google_Service_Datastore_Key();
    $key->setPath([$path]);
    return $key;
}
```

Comment: can't you just remove the `setName` call?  I believe that would cause an `id` to be auto-assigned (avoid the `setId` too unless you're aiming to set a **specific** numeric id).

Comment: if i comment out setName it throws this error: Commit to Cloud Datastore exception: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/<appname>/commit: (400) Key path element must not be incomplete: [testkind: ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Cloud Datastore generate the ID for you by populating the `insertAutoId` field on the mutation instead of the `upsert` field.

Here's a code snippet (adapted from the `datastore_connect.php` file you posted):

```
function create_key() {
  $path = new Google_Service_Datastore_KeyPathElement();
  $path->setKind("testkind");
  // Neither name nor ID is set.
  $key = new Google_Service_Datastore_Key();
  $key->setPath([$path]);
  return $key;
}
function create_entity() {
  $entity = new Google_Service_Datastore_Entity();
  $entity->setKey(create_key());
  // Add properties...
  return $entity;
}
function create_commit_request() {
  $entity = create_entity();
  $mutation = new Google_Service_Datastore_Mutation();
  $mutation->setInsertAutoId([$entity]);  // Causes ID to be allocated.
  $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_CommitRequest();
  $req->setMode('NON_TRANSACTIONAL');
  $req->setMutation($mutation);
  return $req;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a PHP library to take away most of the headache of Cloud Datastore, you could try my new library, which sits on top of the official google-api-php-client:

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

And here's a sample code snippet to create an Entity with an auto-generated ID

```
$obj_book = new GDS\Entity();
$obj_book->title = 'Romeo and Juliet';
$obj_book->author = 'William Shakespeare';
$obj_book->isbn = '1840224339';

// Write it to Datastore
$obj_book_store->upsert($obj_book);
```

More code snippets and documentation on GitHub.

Comment: this looks amazing but I have no idea how to use this without Composer. mind shedding any light on how to get it up and running?

Comment: Well, Composer is used for 2 things: 1. Importing the Google PHP API and 2. Building a class map + autoloader. You'd have to manually do these 2 things. I *strongly* recommend using Composer.